# Picasso's Transformation class to Crop borders from Image

Tags: java, android, image

It's a implementation of [Transformation](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Transformation.html) from [Picasso library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) looks for the first different pixel color in both sides, in the vertical and horizontal, and crops the bitmap from there.

Here is the [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) class doc from Android library.

```
public class CropMiddleFirstPixelTransformation implements Transformation {
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;


    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();

        int[] horizontalMiddleArray = new int[width];
        source.getPixels(horizontalMiddleArray, 0, width, 0, height / 2, width, 1);

        int[] verticalMiddleArray = new int[height];
        source.getPixels(verticalMiddleArray, 0, 1, width / 2, 0, 1, height);

        int left = getFirstNonWhitePosition(horizontalMiddleArray);
        int right = getLastNonWhitePosition(horizontalMiddleArray);

        int top = getFirstNonWhitePosition(verticalMiddleArray);
        int bottom = getLastNonWhitePosition(verticalMiddleArray);

        mWidth = right - left;
        mHeight = bottom - top;


        if (!isNegative(left, right, top, bottom)) {
            return source;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, left, top, mWidth , mHeight);
        source.recycle();
        return bitmap;

    }

    private boolean isNegative(int... values) {
        for (int i : values) {
            if (i < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

    private int getFirstNonWhitePosition(int[] horizontalMiddleArray) {
        int left = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < horizontalMiddleArray.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                left = horizontalMiddleArray[i];
            }
            if (left != horizontalMiddleArray[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private int getLastNonWhitePosition(int[] horizontalMiddleArray) {
        int right = 0;
        int length = horizontalMiddleArray.length;
        for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (i == length - 1) {
                right = horizontalMiddleArray[i];
            }
            if (right != horizontalMiddleArray[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "CropMiddleFirstPixelTransformation(width=" + mWidth + ", height=" + mHeight + ")";
    }
}
```

What could be improved in this implementation?

I think I could eliminate one of this methods: getLastNonWhitePosition, getFirstNonWhitePosition using Java 8 and functional programming, but I cannot do that.

Answer (score 3):

To be fair, I think it is quite readable  and I do not know of a way to really improve it using Java 8 constructs. I have a tip or two anyway:

- In the `getXNonWhitePosition` methods, I'd remove the internal check to assign the first value, assigning it before the loop:

  ```
  private int getFirstNonWhitePosition(int[] horizontalMiddleArray) {
      if(horizontalMiddleArray.length == 0) {
          return -1;
      }
      int left = horizontalMiddleArray[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < horizontalMiddleArray.length; i++) {
          if (left != horizontalMiddleArray[i]) {
              return i;
          }
      }
      return -1;
  }
  ```
- You *could* implement the `isNegative` with a Java 8 stream, e.g.:

  ```
  private boolean isNegative(final int... values) {
      return IntStream.of(values).allMatch(value -> value > 0);
  }
  ```
- Why do you save `mWidth` and `mHeight` in the fields? Because it seems to me like the transformation has nothing to do with it. These values will change after each transformation application. Using them for the `toString` feels quite odd.

If I would really want to use Java 8 for the `getXNonWhitePosition` methods, I think something like the following would do:

```
private int getFirstNonWhitePosition(final int[] horizontalMiddleArray) {
    if(horizontalMiddleArray.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    final int left = horizontalMiddleArray[0];
    return IntStream.range(1, horizontalMiddleArray.length)
            .filter(index -> horizontalMiddleArray[index] != left)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(-1);
}

private int getLastNonWhitePosition(final int[] horizontalMiddleArray) {
    if(horizontalMiddleArray.length == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    final int right = horizontalMiddleArray[horizontalMiddleArray.length - 1];
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, horizontalMiddleArray.length)
            .map(index -> horizontalMiddleArray.length - index)
            .filter(index -> horizontalMiddleArray[index] != right)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(-1);
}
```

This is not tested, though I think it works. But again, I do not think this is much of an improvement. You could technically extract to a function which receives some value to check against, and some kind of indexing stream, but that feels like over engineering to me.